# ARIMA: How to convert row index of type Int64Index (sequential index) to DatetimeIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, statsmodels, arima

Required by statsmodel for ARIMA model, I need to convert a pandas series `ts` into a time series, i.e. a series with row index of type od DatetimeIndex or whatever acceptable to statsmodel ARIMA.

I tried to do the following:

```
ts.index = pandas.DatetimeIndex(ts.index)
```

but I got the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert Int64Index->DatetimeIndex
```

It's just to satisfy the formality of statsmodel. The exact content of the row index does not matter as long it maintains the original sequential order.

Here is the content of `ts`:

```
ts.head()

    0           1
0   -0.801552   1.0
1   -0.997606   2.0
2   -3.659062   3.0
3   -1.193043   4.0
4   -2.858001   5.0
```

Please help me for a solution. Thanks!

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(ts.index, unit='D')` ?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it works. The key is to use to_datetime, even without unit='D' would still work. It would convert to date from 1970-01-01, ...

Comment: Glad to help. If you want to plot using your initial notation (i.e. `t = 0, 1, 2..`) you can always set the index back to int and plot it.